# how i can do the authentification

Tags: hibernate, model-view-controller

My project is a website in JavaEE allows parents to control their children. I have a problem in coding the authentication page.

I have a table in the database named `user`, the attributes are (`id`, `surname`, `first name`, `mail`, `login`, `password` and `type` (`teacher` or `parent` or `admin`)).

In the page login.jsp when you enter login and password, it will look in the database to which account to associate is what admin or parent or teacher.

With login and password "admin" there will be redirection to the admin interface.

How can I do this with the framework hibernate?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the introduction [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  I am missing the "Include details about what you have tried and exactly what you are trying to do." from your question.

Comment: login.jsp:  <html> </head></head>
<body>
<form method="get" action="Authentification">
Login: <input type="text" name="username">
Mot de passe:  <input type="text" name="password">
<input type="submit" value="Connexion">
<a href="Inscription_Parent">Inscription_Parents</a>
</form>

</body>
</html>

Comment: quand je tape comme username :admin and password :admin il faut chercher ces données dans la base si ce sont de type admin il ya redirection vers l'interface de l'admin